# Extend the concept of uniform continuity to uniform convergence.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

This question was given as part of an assignment. The exact question is,

> Extend the concept of uniform continuity to uniform convergence for a sequence of functions.

I know and understand the definition of uniform continuity and uniform convergence, but it is not clear to me how the latter is an extension of the former. I am looking for an answer that does not use terms in topology.

Comment: I’m not sure the following statement is true, but maybe the question is asking you to show something like “$f$ is uniformly continuous on a set $E$ if and only if there exists a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ that converges uniformly to $f$.”